# How are the images of a moving projectile affected by a longer exposure time?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

If there was a series of images of a moving projectile how does making the camera exposure longer affect the images? I was thinking does making the exposure longer result in a less accuracy of the position of the projectile? Due to the longer time interval? I'm not sure how to approach this question.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics.SE! You should tell us more about your thoughts on the problem and be more specific about which aspect bugs you. For example, is it clear to you what "exposure time" means and how long exposures affect the images of moving objects in general?

Comment: If the projectile moves an appreciable amount during the exposure time, then there will obviously be some motion blur in each image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the type of the shutter and also on the flash. With no flash and a central shutter in the lens, moving objects are blurred in the direction of movement. The longer the exposure, the longer the blur on the film (or sensor). With the flash, the effective exposure time is set by the duration of the flash rather than by the shutter and is about 1/1000 sec (with the shutter commonly running at 1/100 - 1/200).

A different and more common type of a shutter is a narrow gap running along the film. This way the effective exposure can be as short as 1/8000 (on some cameras) while the shutter actually runs at about 1/200. In this case, the effect on the film may be different. For example, the wings of the hummingbird are so fast that they are still blurred at 1/1000. If I set the exposure to 1/8000 while the shutter runs at 1/200, I may capture the hummingbird with one wing up and the other down, because the wings change the position while the shutter gap moves from one wing to the other.

With the moving projectile, the result on the film would be different when the shutter moves in the same direction or the opposite direction or perpendicularly to the direction of the projectile. The image would be accordingly longer, shorter, or angled.

New electronic shutters may engage the whole sensor at once or gradually line by line thus producing the results similar to those for the mechanical shutters.